# What does "I wouldn't let him round the bases" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the sentence found in Nebraska movie?

> David Grant: It's hard to imagine you and my mother fighting over the
>   same man.
>   Peg Nagy: I knew I didn't have a chance, anyway.
>   David Grant: Yeah?
>   Peg Nagy: **I wouldn't let him round the bases.**

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's figurative. *Rounding the bases* in a literal sense would be to touch the bases in a game of baseball. However, in a figurative sense, the bases represent different levels of intimacy with a romantic partner. For some idea of what they are, here's an excerpt from Wikipedia, [*Baseball metaphors for sex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball_metaphors_for_sex),

> Among the most commonly used metaphors are the bases describing levels of physical intimacy (generally from a heterosexual perspective). Definitions vary, but the following are typical usages of the terms:
>
> - First base – mouth-to-mouth kissing, especially French kissing;
> - Second base – skin-to-skin touching/kissing of the breasts; in some contexts, it may instead refer to touching any erogenous zones through the clothes (i.e., not actually touching the skin), or manual stimulation of the genitals;
> - Third base – touching below the waist (without sexual intercourse); in some contexts, it may instead refer to oral stimulation of the genitals;
> - Home run (home base or scoring) – "full" sexual intercourse.

So, she knew that she would not win the man because she withheld sexual intimacy from him. Ultimately, I think she's suggesting that she lost because she wouldn't let him have sex with her ("home run", "scoring"). This is often considered a significant reason to end a relationship.